# Rendering a div element inside existing div during page rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-16

I'm stuck at rendering a component insider a div. My code is like  below, I want to render the div with classname RequestNewOrgBtn inside the parentDiv. How can I do it at runtime of render?

```
const labelItem =  Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('label'))
        .find(el => el.textContent === 'External Org Name');
    const parentDiv =  labelItem?.parentNode?.parentNode?.parentNode;

    return(
        <>
            {
                
              //render below div inside parentDiv
                <div className="RequestNewOrgBtn">
                    <Button disabled={false} onClick={onAddClick}>
                        { "Request New External org" }
                    </Button>
                    <RequestExternalOrgModal
                        isOpen={ShowReqExOrgModal}
                        onClose={onReqExOrgModalClose} />
                </div>
            }
        </>
    );
```

Comment: What purpose do you want to use this for that cannot be achieved via CSS? Why not add this code into whatever component is rendering the `parentDiv`?

Comment: The thing is the code that is rendering the parentdiV is using flowable, and I cant access the form components inside flowable, only way i can do it rendering it while page is loading. I really i dont know how to do it via css

Comment: You cannot just move React components around the DOM. Even if you do, while it might look correct presentationally, you will lose event binding like your `onClick={onAddClick}`

Comment: But its not rendered yet, I want to put the logic before div in curly braces, cant we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this would be to render the appropriate parts of your React app into the element in question, similar to how you would render `<App />` into your *root* element.

For example...

```jsx
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

import RequestNewOrgBtn from "./RequestNewOrgBtn"; // your component

const labelItem = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("label")).find(
  (el) => el.textContent === "External Org Name"
);
const parentDiv = labelItem?.parentNode?.parentNode?.parentNode;

if (parentDiv) {
  // create a new root for your button component
  const btnRootElement = document.createElement("div");

  // append it into the found `parentDiv`
  parentDiv.appendChild(btnRootElement);

  const btnRoot = createRoot(btnRootElement);
  btnRoot.render(<RequestNewOrgBtn />);
}
```

[image: Edit unruffled-carson-0qtcfc]

---

For React 16, you just use the `ReactDOM` equivalent

```jsx
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

// ...

ReactDOM.render(<RequestNewOrgBtn />, btnRootElement);
```

Comment: I have react 16, createRoot isnt supported in 16.14

Comment: That should have been part of your question. In that case, you just need to use the ReactDOM equivalent

Comment: thank you sir, it worked, I really appreciate it, finally. I don't have to create a customize flowable component.

Comment: Is there any way I can stop re-rendering it? Reason bc its been rendered many times on page

Comment: thanks, I just figured it out, I added a state variable to that page, and I checking the state before rendering

Comment: @shanky I wasn't aware that you were running this code within a component. You could probably use a [ref](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef) to keep track of any added elements

Comment: I have to provide store manually, wrapping component inside provider to access the state in RequestNewOrgBtn, I don't how can I provide it in another way?

Answer (score -1):

This is a little ambiguous. But, if I am understanding correctly, I think you can set the innerHTML to append the div

```
parentDiv.innerHTML += "<div>Your div content here</div>"
```

better yet, set your div as a variable and then just += the variable for cleaner code.

```
const myDiv = "<div>Your div content here</div>"
parentDiv.innerHTML += myDiv
```

Used [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to make sure I was remembering correctly

Comment: There's a big difference between some static HTML and a React component

Comment: Sorry, I am kind of new to interacting on Stack Overflow and didn't know where to look for the tags (I usually just find this place through google). I didn't see the react tag. My bad. But, I know where to look now.